# IE not response to a checkbox ticked by a VBA code

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, checkbox

I’m trying to write  VBA code to control IE automatic extract data from a local intranet website . Everything work ok with the default setting of the website. However when i change the criteria of input data by a VBA code for ticking a checkbox on the website, the website seems not to be activated (checkbox not visible although it checked), then the website extract empty data while with the same input there is data extracted when I manually doing it.

Please help me out on this issue. Thank you.

[This is when i manually select the checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KdDS.png)

[This is when VBA code select the checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48ana.jpg)

My VBA Code:

```
Sub ExractData()
            Dim URL As String
            Dim btnTaiBaocao As Object
            Dim DkVantin As Object
            Dim DataVanTin As Object
            Dim TenDangNhap As Object
            Dim MatKhau As Object
            Dim btnDangNhap As Object
            Dim iepopup As Object
            Dim hWND As Long
            Dim childHWND As Long
            Dim lr_stk As Long
            Dim k As Long
                    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
                        ie.Visible = True
                        URL = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                        ie.Navigate (URL)
                    Do
                    DoEvents
                    Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4
                    Set TenDangNhap = ie.Document.getElementById("txtNameAdmin")
                    TenDangNhap.Value = Sheet1.Range("g1")
                    Set MatKhau = ie.Document.getElementById("txtPassword")
                    MatKhau.Value = Sheet1.Range("g2")
                    Set btnDangNhap = ie.Document.getElementById("btnLogin")
                    btnDangNhap.Click
            
                    lr_stk = Sheet2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                    For k = 2 To lr_stk
                         Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
                         ie.Visible = True
                
                         URL = Sheet4.Range("H2").Value
                         ie.Navigate (URL)
                     
                         Do
                             DoEvents
                         Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4
                                        
                        ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddType").selectedindex = Sheet4.Range("H3").Value
                        ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoActOld").fireevent ("onchange")
                        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:3"))
                        ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoActOld").Checked = True
                        Set DataVanTin = ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCIF_TK")
                        DataVanTin.Value = Sheet2.Range("J" & k)
                        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:1"))
                         Set btnTaiBaocao = ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDownload")
                        btnTaiBaocao.Click
                        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"))
           ' ……….
                    Next k
End Sub
```

Web page source:

```html
<td align="left" class="auto-style4">
                                                                                    <span style="font-size:Small;"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoActNew" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$sdoAct" value="rdoActNew" checked="checked" tabindex="4" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoActNew">NewCore</label></span>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td width="70">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                                <td align="left" class="auto-style4">
                                                                                    <span style="font-size:Small;"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoActOld" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$sdoAct" value="rdoActOld" tabindex="5" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoActOld">OldCore</label></span>
                                                                                </td>
```

Comment: Do you want to select the "OldCore" radio button? If so, you can try to click the button using the code like this: `ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoActOld").Click`. Tell us if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try .Checked = “checked” instead of true and it’s possible that you have to use extra quotes around checked. And you have already set IE at the start, i think you can leave this part out in the loop (will make it faster to).